# chartjs - line chart - fixed values in axis - 2 dataset - no overlapping lines and points

Tags: charts

I have a line chart where x axis are fixed values (a,b,c,d,e) and y axis are also fixed values (A,B,C,D,E)

Also I have two datasets (data1 and data2), where have the same value in the same coordinate (for examle x:b y:B), so the two lines overlapping

it there a way to move a little one of the points to avoid the overlapping?. I want to see all points of datasets.

Thanks!

Comment: here are the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanrc/5dz1aoLu/11/. as you can see,  only shows  one line of points. I want to see the two lines of points, moving a little bit one of them.